# external css and js not loading in inner pages nodejs express

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am creating a blog application using `nodejs` and express with `ejs`. everything is working fine with a single `URL` ( means http://localhost/ or http://localhost/anything ), but when I am trying to access a page `http://localhost/blog/create` in this page external `stylesheet` or `javascript` not working, it's loading as `http://localhost/blog/css/style.css` (it should be `http://localhost/css/style.css)`.

I am using middleware static to load `css` and `js` from public directory

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

header and footer are loading using `<%- include('./partials/header') %>`

Directory Structure:

```
View Files : views
header & footer : views/Partials
css and js : public
```

Comment: show the codes where you are loading the css?

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

Comment: `href="css/style.css">` -> ./css/style.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your style sheet should use `'/css/style.css'` instead of `'css/style.css'`

There are some good explanations here
[Absolute vs relative URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls)